# Because the plugin below does not work when used in the response of a getJSON

Tags: jquery, plugins, reverse

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.reverse = function(fn) {       
       var i = this.length;
       while(i--) {
           fn.call(this[i], i, this[i])
       }
    };   
}(jQuery));
```

Below the use of jquery code with alphabetical data

```
$.fn.reverse ($response, function (k, v) {
    $("#selector").append('<tr><td>' + v.name + '</td></tr>');
});
```

Comment: `$($response).reverse(function (k, v) {...`

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the plugin to any jQuery object, so you need to do something like this to use the plugin.

```
$($response).reverse(function (k, v) { /*.. code here ...*/ });
//-^^^- wrap using jQuery if it's not a jQuery object
```

Refer : [How to Create a Basic Plugin](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/)